# Restoring geometry after the first page

Tags: geometry, afterpage

I tried this and it did not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=0.5in}
\afterpage{\restoregeometry}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

UPDATE:

I'm aware that "the restoregeometry command can work fine without a call to `\afterpage`. " But in this case I'm using it for the specific purpose of *automatically* placing `\restoregeometry` on page 2. The alternative would be to insert `\newpage\restoregeometry`. But I want to avoid having to *manually* set a new page.

[image]

Comment: Try to explain better what it is that you want to achieve. Either way, the restoregeometry command can work fine without a call to afterpage. Take a loot at the package manual, the section about newgeometry and the like is clearly explained.

Comment: if you only want that the first page starts higher, use \vspace*{-XXcm}

Comment: don't use newgeometry or afterpage here